# c# virtual generic factory method

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, factory-method

I have a project with a base assembly that uses a factory class. For each sub-project using that base assembly, I then override the factory methods for each sub-type as follows:

```
// BASE FACTORY IN BASE ASSEMBLY
public class InitFactory : InitFactoryBase {
  public static InitFactoryBase Initializer = new InitFactoryBase();
  //
  public virtual BaseObject newBaseObject1() { return new BaseObject1(); }
  public virtual BaseObject newBaseObject2() { return new BaseObject2(); }
}

public class BaseObject1 {....}
public class BaseObject2 {....}


// PROJECT MAIN FUNCTION
[STAThread]
static void Main() {
   // make sure the initializer we use is the one defined in our project...
   InitFactoryBase.Initializer = new InitFactory();
   [....]
}
// MY_PROJECT USING BASE ASSEMBLY
public class InitFactory : InitFactoryBase {
  public virtual BaseObject newBaseObject1() { return new MyObject1(); }
  public virtual BaseObject newBaseObject2() { return new MyObject2(); }
}
public class MyObject1 : BaseObject1 {....}
public class MyObject2 : BaseObject2 {....}
```

Basically, my "InitFactory" is a virtual factory class that can be overwritten in projects to use project-specific derived objects. Note that it is not abstract because it MUST NOT be derived from, which is on purpose.

Now this is quite cumbersome as I have many derived classes of the type 'MyObject1' and it makes it hard to maintain the code properly.

The key here is that I want to "replace" the base type in the assembly with a derived type in the project and cast elements wherever required.

I am pretty sure there are better approaches for that using generics or any other method I am not aware of. Any suggestion?

Comment: From my experience, trying to make generic or subclassed factories provides little to no benefit.  Unless your use case is more complicated than the example you gave, you'd probably be better off using a DI framework, like CastleWindsor for example, and just removing the factories altogether.

Comment: @jdraper3 Yep, I cam accross Ninject as well, but I wasn't quite sure about it... Any comments welcome!